# optimization: stream of many key updates, small number of keys

Tags: optimization, data-structures, hash, hashtable, hashset

I have a program that receives a constant stream of data.

From this stream of data I populate a hashtable. Every piece of data I receive
is translated in, either:

- a **key update** ;
- or a **key insertion** if it doesn't already exist.

I store the incoming **raw** data in a **queue** before it is being processed.

The number of keys in the hashtable is very small. 99% of the data I receive
corresponds to **key updates**.

The problem is that I have so many key updates that the queue becomes
**too big** for my consumers.

Obviously, from the thousands of key updates, many of them concern the same
key, so only the last one has a real value while all the others are useless.

What is the best way for me to handle this case? Which data structure should I
be using?

> What can you tell us about your keys? How many are there? Are they numeric (and if so, what range of values might they take?), textual? Any limit on the number of bytes per key? What kind of hash table are you inserting to (e.g. closed hashing, open hashing)? What contention/locking is there on the hash table? How many updates per second? What programming language are you using?

#### How many keys

A few hundreds or maybe a few thousands. Not a lot!

#### Numeric keys

The keys themselves are alphanumeric, they are not very long, around 30 characters at most. The values, however, are all numbers (integers).

#### Limit on the number of bytes per key

My keys are 30 characters long, at most.

#### Kind of hash table

I'm simply using Python's `defaultdict`

#### Contention/locking

Python's dictionaries are considered thread-safe

#### Number of updates per second

It can go from 1 every 3 seconds to more than a 100 per second

#### Programming language

I'm using python

Comment: What can you tell us about your keys?  How many are there?  Are they numeric (and if so, what range of values might they take?), textual?  Any limit on the number of bytes per key?  What kind of hash table are you inserting to (e.g. closed hashing, open hashing)?  What contention/locking is there on the hash table?  How many updates per second?  What programming language are you using?

Comment: @TonyD I added answers to all your questions in my question!

Comment: Sounds tricky.  Did you try making the updates directly in the `defaultdict`, instead of putting them through a queue?  It might seem counter-intuitive, but if you can do that fast enough not to get flooded by or drop input, you avoid multiple values for the same key hanging around in memory, and may reduce memory allocation and synchronisation overheads.  Is the input stream TCP, UDP, higher level events e.g. ZooKeeper...?  You might be able to use a trie approach, or even remove duplicates for the same key in an intermediate program or library using e.g. C or C++, reducing load on python.

Comment: What does processing the raw data entail? I guess my real question is where is your bottleneck? The dictionary lookup and update? Or processing the data before you update the dictionary? If the latter, you could probably greatly improve your throughput by using a stack instead of a queue, and putting a timestamp on the data when it goes onto the stack, and a last update timestamp on the data in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a simple queue you can use another hashtable - each incoming message could be stored in the appropriate stack based on key. You then take each element from each stack (which will be the most recent item) - you can optionally clear each stack when you pull an item out.

Comment: great idea! what if I `pop()` from the stack and then clear the stack but in the meantime a new update got `put()` on the stack? am i going to lose it?

Comment: You have to have some protection mechanism in place between producer / consumer (if they're different threads) whatever data structure you use.

Answer (score 0):

[ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369(v=vs.110).aspx) should fit the bill nicely.

But what you need here is an (maybe adaptive) throttling mechanism, that detects when the queue is too slow and starts collapsing the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I need something instantaneous. I cannot wait for the queue to start being too big to do something about it, it needs to be real-time!

Comment: You need to measure exactly and see what your bottlenecks are. Most often, any kind of performance problems can be solved via business/domain-specific optimizations.